# SQLAlchemy connection fails on the first attempt to connect but succeeds on subsequent

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

Following the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy), the simplest way to connect is to create an `Engine` and run `connect()` method.

```
connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute("select 1")
print(result.fetchall())
connection.close()
```

However, I get an error when attempting to do so.

> [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]111214;An attempt to complete a transaction has failed. No corresponding transaction found. (111214) (SQLEndTran)

Strangely, running this code will work twice though, only when done in two separate batches. All subsequent executions will then work too. Is there a better way to be connecting?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from a Windows machine or a non-Windows machine?

Comment: Try using FreeTDS and see if you have the same behavior https://bitbucket.org/janihur/devoops/wiki/How_To_Connect_Azure_SQL_Database_From_Ubuntu

Comment: What happens if you skip the `connection = engine.connect()` and just do `print(engine.execute("SELECT 1").fetchall())` ...?